# Update Leaflet Marker based on timer in Shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have data frame `df` which has two variables `lat` and `lon`, Now I need to create a Shinydashboard which updates the map by taking next row value in from the data frame after every `10 seconds`.

`df`

```
 df <- data.frame("Lat" = c(12.8882, 12.890, 12.891), "Lon" = c(77.58195,77.58190,77.581958))
```

`Ui.R`

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
shinyUI( fluidPage(
                leafletOutput("map1")
                   )
        )
```

`server.R`

```
library(shiny)

 shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

 output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
                      leaflet() %>%
                        addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
                        addMarkers(lng=df$lon, lat=df$lat)})
                               })
```

Only thing I know is I can use `invalidateLater()` to call the timer but I do not know how to implement that for the incremental reading of the rows in the data frame.

`Expected Result`

I need a map where the `marker` moves to the next position after every `10 Seconds`, The coordinates for moving the marker is given through the data frame `df`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a `reactiveVal()` to keep track of the currently displayed marker, and use `observe()` in combination with `invalidateLater()` and `leafletProxy()` to remove the previous marker and add the new one. To do so we can give the layer a `layerId` everytime we add our marker, which we can then use to remove the marker again when plotting the next marker.

A working example is given below, I added some comments to illustrate what is happening. Hope this helps!

---

[image]

---

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
set.seed(1)

df <- cbind(rnorm(40) * 2 + 13, rnorm(40) + 48)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Create the base map
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite,
                       options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)
      ) %>%
      setView(lng = mean(rnorm(1000) * 2 + 13), lat =  mean(rnorm(1000) + 48), zoom = 7)
  })

  # Initialize a reactiveVal to keep track of which point is currently selected
  point_to_plot <- reactiveVal(1)

  observe({
    # invalidate every 2 seconds
    invalidateLater(2000)
    isolate({
      # update point_to_plot() to next value. If next value is higher than the amount of rows
      # in df, set it to 1.
      point_to_plot(ifelse(point_to_plot()+1<=nrow(df),point_to_plot()+1,1))
      # Use leafletProxy to remove our previous marker, and add the new one.
      leafletProxy('mymap') %>%
        removeMarker('my_marker') %>%
        addMarkers(layerId = 'my_marker',data = df[point_to_plot(),,drop=F])
    })
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

> EDIT: Working example with your data:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame("Lat" = c(12.8882, 12.890, 12.891), "Lon" = c(77.58195,77.58190,77.581958))

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Create the base map
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite,
                       options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)
      ) %>%
      setView(lat = 12.89, lng = 77.58195, zoom = 14)
  })

  # Initialize a reactieVal to keep trakc of which point is currently selected
  point_to_plot <- reactiveVal(1)

  observe({
    # invalidate every 2 seconds
    invalidateLater(2000)
    isolate({
      # update point_to_plot() to next value. If next value is higher than the amount of rows
      # in df, set it to 1.
      point_to_plot(ifelse(point_to_plot()+1<=nrow(df),point_to_plot()+1,1))
      # Use leafletProxy to remove our previous marker, and add the new one.
      leafletProxy('mymap') %>%
        removeMarker('my_marker') %>%
        addMarkers(layerId = 'my_marker',data = df[point_to_plot(),,drop=F])
    })
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: @ANmike please see my edit, I added a working example with the data you provided.

Comment: Great, glad I could help! :)

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks @Florian!  I was trying to modify it to use multiple points. As a quick modification, if instead of 

df[point_to_plot(),,drop=F] 

I have 

df[point_to_plot() + 0:1,,drop=F], it still only plots one point. (It also eventually crashes b/c of subscript out of range but I can fix that).   Do you know what else would have to be edited?

Comment: Hi @bmac, this is quite extensive for discussion in the comments, it's also not fully clear what your expected result is to me. Please consider opening a new question on SO, and I'll see if I can help you along :)

Comment: Ok great, thanks @Florian!  I'll write up a question in the next day or so, and post a link here once it is written.  Basically, I'm interested in showing multiple points/markers moving along different straight line paths.  This could potentially be accomplished by adapting the code above so that it shows multiple points in each frame and reducing invalidLater to a much smaller number.